# Document size in DocuValue table in Dynamics-AX-2009

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

My customer has stored some quite large Documents (>40MB...don't ask..) in the Axapta Document System. While these documents are stored well on the MS SQL Server 2008 DB and can be read and exported there via BCP, they cannot accessed within AX.
Using the standard document handling form the corresponding DocuValue record cannot be found.
When I try to locate the record via table browser and recid, the record is "partially" shown. Name field is filled correctly but file_ is empty. And the record is shown as a new record with '*' at the start.

This only happens for DocuValue records with large documents > ca. 10MB. Everything smaller works fine.

I can only suspect there is a relation to the server configuration parameter MaxBufferSize. This is set to 26 on this server.

Is there a way to fix this problem or is AX not able to handle that document size well at all ?

Edit:

This seems to be client related. Accessing the documents with a true physical Windows 10 client machine is possible, while with the virtual Windows 2008 R2 server I use to run the AX client it fails. Will do some more research in that direction.

Answer (score 2):

There is a maximum RPC setting in the registry that limits the maximum size of a packet sent between the AOS and the client. This option isn't exposed by the server configuration tool but needs to be changed in the registry.

[This document](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/emeadaxsupport/2009/04/23/rpc-packet-size-limit-causes-trouble-in-the-dynamics-ax-document-handling/) is for 4.0 but the same setting is available for 2009.

There is also the maximum file size in the document handling parameters that you can check.

I personally wouldn't muck with the Maximum RPC size as that can cause other performance issues, but if you want to store large files in AX don't store them in the database but store them in a file share (this is also configurable in the document handling parameters)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the links to both the KB articles in the linked document don't work for me. But it lead me to some more digging around.
It turned out, that one of the servers had MaxBufferSize NOT set in registry. After setting it I at least can attach big files on this server.
Still can't read it again, but this seems to be client related - see my original post.

Comment: You should still be storing them on a file share if they are big @michaelkonz